# Jetpack infinite scroll not working on Twenty Twelve

Tags: plugin-jetpack, theme-twenty-twelve

I just updated **Jetpack** and the theme, and the **infinite scroll** doesn't work anymore.

I have tracked the console, and the **XHR** does receive the content of the posts to add but somehow it isn't displaying them.

My blog is: http://jorjon.com/blog/

I have **no custom modification** whatsoever.

**Update:** Thanks to [Jared](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/6737/jared-cobb), I have found this Javascript console error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery.js:2
v.extend.parseJSON jquery.js:2
(anonymous function) infinity.js:208
l jquery.js:2
c.fireWith jquery.js:2
T jquery.js:2
r
```

**Update 2:** This is what is being returned by the **XHR**, supposedly there is an unexpected token there, but I can't find anything. The JSON at the last line, as Jared mentioned, is Valid. http://pastebin.com/ZUD2xqun

Comment: Yep, very strange.  I'm getting a JavaScript error `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character`.  So I inspected the response, did a copy/paste of the JSON into [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) and was told `Valid JSON`.  At which point I up-voted your question because I'm now curious too!

Comment: Hi jared, thanks for your time! I will check if I didn't add some strange character that is messing with the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the response should be JSON only. Not some HTML with JSON at the end.

Seems like the WordPress SEO plugin installed uses output buffering to output the meta tags in the HTML header. Have you tried deactivating this plugin or others? Maybe you can deactivate output buffering in the plugin alltogether.